# PowerMock.VerifyStatic alternate in mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermock, powermockito

`PowerMock.verifyStatic(Util.class)`

I use this method in powermockito to verify this class, What is the method I need to use in mockito to verify the similar behaviour ?

Comment: I saw this, everyone is using powermockito here. Is powermockito is the only way, I have to do this in mockito , is it possible ?

Comment: Have you checked javadoc: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Comment: Yeah I checked the doc but I cant find anything useful.